# Падежное окончание: "коньяка" или "коньяку"?

Tags: орфография, морфология

Как правильно: "ложка коньяка" или "коньяку"?

Answer (score 6):

Согласна с Виктором: обе формы допустимы, но в современном языке в именных сочетаниях типа кусок воска, сахара, стакан чая партитив (с "-у") уже уступает место генитиву по причине, имеющей семантическую природу: лексические значения  существительных (кусок, кило, стакан) означают фиксируемые носителями языка определенные количества измеряемых объектов. В случае  конкуренции партитива и генитива в количественном значении партитив преимущественно применяют при выражении неопределенного количества, генитив – при обозначении количества определенного (см. [здесь](http://archive.nbuv.gov.ua/portal/Soc_Gum/Ros_fil/2008_2/7.html)).
Кроме того, в литературе отмечается стилистическая сниженность (разговорность и “народность”) форм родительного падежа с флексиями -у(-ю) [Розенталь 2007, 427].
О вариантах [здесь](http://slovari.ru/default.aspx?s=0&p=5312&0a0=1712).

У нас тоже ИМЕННОЕ сочетание ложка коньяка. Ложка - определённое количество, значит, преимущество за родительным - генитивом. Ложка коньяка (определённое колич.), но выпить коньяку (неопред. колич.) Ложка коньяку - народное традиционное, т. е. разговорное.

Answer (score 3):

Существительные мужского рода 2 склонения в Р.п.ед.ч. могут иметь вариантные окончания-а(-я) и -у(-ю).окончание -у (-ю) является разговорным.  Как вариантное (дополнительное) окончание -у (-ю) может употребляться  у вещественных существительных при указании на количество:ложка коньяку, стакан чаю, кусок сыру.

Answer (score 2):

Обе формы допустимы, так же как "сахара - сахару, меда - меду...", но форма с -у считается разговорной, менее книжной.

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю, всё же «коньяку» звучит более оригинально.
Коньяк это благородный напиток, который пьётся из шкалика, как говорили наши славянские предки, «рюмку коньяку, откушать шкалик водочки», а не *выжрать бутылку водки*. Или *бутылку коньяка*.

Comment: Много эиоций, мало смысла.

Answer (score 0):

Если немного - то ложка коньяку. Если речь идёт о большом количестве, то окончание -а: Завод выпустил три тонны коньяка.
Это относится и к другим словам мужского рода, обозначающим вещества: Стакан чаю и две ложки сахару. Но: Чаеводы собрали большой урожай чая. На станцию прибыло десять вагонов сахара.

Answer (score 0):

Рюмка коньяка (определённое количество), но выпить коньяку(неопределённое количество), все предложения отвечают на вопрос чего (Р. П.).

Налить в стакан кефира - неправильно. Выпить кефиру - правильно. Лежит головка чеснока - правильно. Съесть чесноку - правильно. Сделать глоток чая - правильно. Напиться чаю - правильно. Задать жарУ - правильно. Прибавить ходУ - правильно. 
ОгонькУ не найдется? - правильно.

Однако у Ожегова в словаре - "Коньяк (а), (у)"- не делается различий. Там же есть - "Стакан чаю". "Пригласить на чашку чая" . "Позвать к чаю" - у Ожегова без вариантов.

Comment: *Налить в стакан кефира - неправильно* - это еще почему?

Answer (score 0):

То же самое, что "чая" и "чаю"; "мёда" и "мёду".  
 
Родительный падеж (кого? чего?): 
1) чая, **коньяка** - какого-нибудь; 
1.а) чая - горячего, крепкого (с какими качествами; определённого приготовления); **коньяка** - трёхзвёздочного/пятизвёздочного; 
1.б) чая - определённой марки из нескольких сортов (зелёного/черного, индийского/английского) со свойствами отдельными; **коньяка** - Армянского, Французского; 
2) чаю, **коньяку** - сколько-нибудь: 
2.а) чаю, **коньяку** - количество (капель, грамм); 
2.б) чаю, **коньяку** - мера (чашка, стакан, ложка).

Answer (score 0):

Почему никто не учитывает неодушевлённости предмета?! Ложка (чего?) мёда (не мёду). Выпить (что? не кого?!) коньяк ( не коньяку). Принесите (что?) сахар (не сахара, не сахару).