# Почему "кусочек сахару"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

В школьных учебниках — "сахару". Но ведь род. падеж: кусочек чего? Сахара.

Comment: http://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/16983/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8C%D1%8F%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8C%D1%8F%D0%BA%D1%83/16993#16993

Answer (score 4):

**Вариантное окончание У/Ю**  для существительных м.р. в Р.п., наряду с основным окончанием А/Я,  используется в  вещественных (а также собирательных) существительных   **при указании на часть или количество**, в том числе со словами **отрицания** при отсутствии количества: выпить чаю (или чая), чашка чая (или чаю), нет сахара или сахару.

«Как так –  нет сахару? – удивляется Таня. – Есть!»
Прошу вас, чашечку кофе. Правда, у нас нет сахара.

**Примечания:**

В именных сочетаниях **чаще** используется окончание А/Я, а в глагольных – окончание У/Ю.

При наличии **определения** пишется окончание А/Я: стакан горячего чая.

В существительных **с суффиксом К** пишется окончание У/Ю: выпить чайку, взять сахарку.

Comment: >> *В именных сочетаниях чаще используется окончание У/Ю, а в глагольных – окончание А/Я.* Скорей уж стакан чая, чем выпить чая.

Comment: Проверяем в Нацкорпусе: стакан чая/чаю - 136:154, выпил чая/чаю - 1:64. Да,  в именных сочетаниях почти поровну, а в глагольных  сочетаниях  обычно используется У/Ю - выпить чаю.

Comment: То есть у вас в предыдущем посте описка?

Comment: Да, проверила по учебнику Грамматика-80, там в именных сочетаниях чаще встречается А/Я, а в глагольных  У/Ю. Исправлю ответ.